# Express-sessions Returns 400 Error With Session Cookie Set With Large Cookies, And Only on AWS Fargate

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, express-session, aws-fargate

My website is an expressjs application that gets packaged into a docker image, and runs in AWS Fargate behind an ALB. Users with a large amount of cookies on the domain (~7KB) encounter a 400 HTTP Error. However, if the user clears their cookies, the problem clears up, at least for a few days until the deleted cookies get reinstalled. I am one subdomain on this domain, and I do not have the political influence to reduce the cookie count, or how the cookies get installed; I work for a large company.

I've eliminated the ALB has the cause of the error. The CloudWatch Metric, HTTPCode_ELB_4XX_Count is 0, while the HTTPCode_Target_4XX_Count spikes as I test this bug.

My diagnostic setup is as follows:
In my preproduction AWS account, I've set the `DEBUG` environment variable to `*` on the container. I've also reduced the Target Group's health check to run every 5 minutes (to reduce chatter), and reduced the task count to 1 (to centralize logs into one cwlog stream). Expressjs should log any incoming requests it routes, with similar verbosity to the [Expressjs's debugging page](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html), however, **absolutely nothing is outputted** in the log. It's as if the request is not reaching expressjs. I thought maybe I botched the setup, but testing it in incognito mode prints many debugging statements.

Using Postman, I've copied the cookie header from Chrome CDT; I continue to get the same 400 result with a `Connection: close` header included in the response. I am using the `express-sessions` module, and if I delete the session cookie (`connect.sid`), the request works. If I delete all cookies except for `connect.sid` (preserving the old value), the request works. If I send all cookies, but update `connect.sid` to the value returned by `Set-Cookie`, the request works.

If I try the same tests locally using `docker-compose`, I am unable to reproduce the 400 error response issue. The docker images are the same in both docker-compose and fargate. Both use postgres by way of the `connect-pg-simple` module as the session store. So potentially, there could be something in the AWS network stack or the AWS Fargate runtime environment.

Relevant dependencies in package.json:

```
    "connect-pg-simple": "^5.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-session": "^1.11.1",
    "helmet": "^3.15.0",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "pg": "^7.6.1",
```

Here are some excerpts of my code. I've included the other setup libraries, in case they conflict, though omitted passport.

```
const express = require('express');
const compression = require('compression');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const pg = require('pg');
const session = require('express-session');
const pgSession = require('connect-pg-simple')(session);
const sessionStore = new pgSession({
    pool: new pg.Pool()
  });

const app = express();
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(compression());
app.use(helmet({
  // helmet settings omitted
}));
app.enable('trust proxy');    // Process X-Forwarded-* headers
app.use(session({
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true
  },
  name: 'connect.sid',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: 'some secret here',
  store: sessionStore
}));
// rest of the code
```

I'd be happy to receive any tips, pointers, suggestions, clarification questions. After spending several hours on this, I could use a fresh perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Through the conversation I had on the [bug report](https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/657) I logged with the express-session module, I've found the answer. In [November 2018](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/vulnerability/november-2018-security-releases/#denial-of-service-with-large-http-headers-cve-2018-12121), the max http header length was reduced from 80KB to 8KB to address a CVE. This affected all supported versions of nodejs (v6, v8, v10) For those facing similar issues, upgrade to the latest micro-version of nodejs, which introduces the [--max-http-header-size flag](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_max_http_header_size_size). For nodejs v10, this was introduced in [v10.15](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V10.md#2018-12-26-version-10150-dubnium-lts-mylesborins).